# How to use aggfunc in Pandas to count categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a series of pivot tables, one of which is to count a series of categoricals. It should be straightforward: pivot on [image]

The code to create it is simple enough:

```
pd.pivot_table(diary, values='type', index=['month', 'day'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

...but my aggfunc isn't right. All I want is the number of cases by day. I know this is basic, but can someone show me the right function to show the count, please?

Comment: What is your expected output for this table?

Comment: Jan 3: 6, Jan4: 2, Jan5: 4 if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['KKKKKK','KK','KKKK']}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Jan'],[3,4,5]]))

df['type'].str.count('K')
```

Output:

```
Jan  3    6
     4    2
     5    4
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @elksie5000 Does this help?